# Rundeck Version Upgrade to 3.3.9

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb, rundeck

We have been trying to upgrade Rundeck from 3.2.8 to 3.3.4 and above. We are facing issues with the JDBC connectors since mysql JDBC connectors are no longer bundled with Rundeck distributions.
We have followed the Rundeck Recommendations with the jdbc connectors, but still facing some issues on the DB end. Here are a few issues we noticed in the logs, please help

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

*[2021-02-25T18:17:34,886] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@515f550a;ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@515f550a*

*[2021-02-25T18:12:10,067] ERROR StackTrace - Full Stack Trace:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=19299) Unknown column 'workflowst1_.expand_token_in_script_file' in 'field list'
*

*Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.MariaDbSqlException: Unknown column 'workflowst1_.expand_token_in_script_file' in 'field list'*

*java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@515f550a;ClassLoader:org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@515f550a*

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/mysql.html#using-mysql-as-a-database-backend) you need to change the driver class name to org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver, then restart rundeck.

Comment: yes, we did that initially during our upgrade and when we tried to execute the jobs on the UI, we were seeing an "internal 500" error with "*[2021-02-25T18:12:10,067] ERROR StackTrace - Full Stack Trace: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=19299) Unknown column 'workflowst1_.expand_token_in_script_file' in 'field list' * so we had to roll back.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with liquibase migrations. I created a new schema in the database and compared it to my current schema and realized that one column was missing, that worked for me.

```
ALTER TABLE `rundeck`.`workflow_step` ADD COLUMN `expand_token_in_script_file` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `adhoc_execution`;
```

Comment: We got the next error after this one (about column `child_nodes`). Then we found DB migration instructions on https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.4.html#db-migration , which did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66424314/10426011) solution you can download and use the MySQL driver to keep your configuration, take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/aqB1WADmH0I/m/5gvWKK8mBwAJ) guide.

Also, make sure that you're defined `dataSource.dbCreate = update` on your rundeck-config.properties config file.